# Descargar archivos y encriptar cada uno c#

Tags: c#

necesito de su opinion estoy haciendo un webservice que me bajara archivos de un servidor automaticamente cada cierto tiempo, actualmente tengo 3 archivos de prueba en el servidor pero quiero que haga lo siguiente, que cuando bajen lo hagan encriptados y al mismo tiempo cree otro archivo con diferente nombre pero desencriptado, actualmente lo hago con una rutina pero en un solo archivo me hace la lectura de los 3 archivos, y yo quiero que me haga un archivo por cada uno que baja del servidor, es en c#

```
foreach (ArchivoProceso f in files)
{
    try
    {
        fichero = f.FileLocal;//esta seria la ruta donde lee los archivos
        sFile = "";   
        using (StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(fichero))
        {
            while (lector.Peek() > -1)
            {
                string linea = lector.ReadLine();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linea))
                {
                    sFile = f.FileLogLocalEncrypt;
                    using (StreamWriter line = File.AppendText(sFile))
                    {
                        line.WriteLine(Encryption(linea));
                        line.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error",e);
    }
}
return true;
}
```

esta la rutina que uso para encriptar pero si quisiera que cuando me baje los archivos lo haga un archivo independiente y no todo el contenido en uno solo, no se sime doy a explicar.
tambien tengo un pequeño problema me duplica las lineas en el archivo creado

Comment: En donde se supone que esta la ruta donde guardas, en sFile?

Comment: esa variable guardara la ruta delarchivo que tomara los datos, en otra rutina esta esa variable donde crea el archivo que seria esta sFile = f.FileLogLocalEncrypt;

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Entonces no entiendo tu problema. Mas alla que no se que hace esa funcion, si devuelve un nombre de archivo distinto para cada archivo vas a crear distintos archivos.. Cual es la duda? mira que no sabemos que es ArchivoProceso o FileLogLocalEncrypt

Comment: Archivo proceso es una clase y el fileloglocalencrypt es el archivo que crea para guardar lo encryptado de la lectura del archivo.  si lo que quiero es crear distintos archivos, porque fichero = f.FileLocal; f.filelocal hay 3 archivos en esa ruta pero a la hora de encryptar me uno todo el contenido en un solo archivo

Comment: Porque estas guardando todo vos en uno.. no se que solucion queres o esperas.. no concemos esas clases.. y por cada archivo, podrias poner un nombre distinto y listo... que esperas como solucion?

Comment: alguna idea de como guardar en diferentes archivos nada mas.

Comment: si, poneles nombres diferentes...